# Need help changing google script code

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using Google script to create a form that submits the information onto a spreadsheet. The first field that is filled in is a PO#. Every time the box is clicked in, the PO# automatically adds 1 and then puts a "-" after it. I am trying to figure out how to change my code so that I can put the letters "CF" in front of the PO#. The final output would be "CFXXXXX-". Can you please help me with this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82nYf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the best with Google Forms, but this can easily be done on Google Sheets using the scripts. If you're not comfortable with that, from your spreadsheet where the data is logged to, you can create a Google Sheets function (like an Excel function) to concatenate **CF** onto the front of the PO #.

A little confused on your increment by one thing without using Google Sheets.

Hopefully this helped a little.